# Cordova - Youtube iFrame Embed - Fullscreen No Video

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, youtube

This is a weird issue. Running on Cordova Android, if I have a iFrame embed Youtube video with width and height set to 100%:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2Xk744838J4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When switching to fullscreen using the native control, the screen becomes black. No video, but audio keeps playing. Rotating the screen doesn't help.

If I set a fixed width and height:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2Xk744838J4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When switching to fullscreen, at first the screen is still black. Once I rotate the screen, the video shows. Better than the first scenario.

Sometimes it just work for both scenarios, but most of the time, it has issues as described above.

I'm running on Android 7.0, Samsung S7. Is it just my device, or some kind of bug?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on my Galaxy S6 Edge running Android 7.0. I noticed that the Android YouTube app forces and locks landscape orientation when viewing a video fullscreen. I will attempt to do the same with the Cordova Screen Orientation plugin but some users may find this jarring as they are accustomed to full screen portrait orientation working also.
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Comment: @Shawn: I have the same issue with S7. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: With this, it sometime shows the video in fullscreen, but not always: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12906

Comment: Well, I have to use fixed dimensions and use JavaScript to dynamically adjust them.

Comment: Please post an answer if you have a fix for this.